# Le Chatelier's Principle Having No Effect

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

Consider the following equilibrium system:

$$\ce{2 IBr(g) <=> I2(g) + Br2(g)}$$

Would a decrease in the volume of the system effect the equilibrium?

I think it would not affect the equilibrium of the system.

This is because a decrease in volume would increase the pressure of the system. Le Chatelier's principle states that a decrease in volume would favour the side with less moles. Since both sides have an equal amount of moles, there would be no shifting of equilibrium.

A decrease in volume would also increase the overall concentration of all substances within the system. Considering that it affects the overall concentration and not just one side, an increase in concentration would merely increase the rate of reaction. Not the equilibrium of the system.

Comment: I see it as right evaluation.

Comment: This is assuming you are operating in the case where there are no deviations from ideal gas behavior. Given the size of these molecules, that is highly unlikely.

Comment: Are you responding to Poutnik or me? Is it highly unlikely that it would not affect equilibrium?